# Inserting data into MySQL is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a simple student register to some college depends on their `STUDENT_ID` and `PASSWORD`.

After they log in it shows to them some information they must fill like "first name, last name, birthdate, degree, etc.". When I am trying to insert these items of information, it does not work.

Database name: `users`, table name: `members_info`. Here is the code I use:

**index.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<form action="login.php?login=yes" method="post" name="login">
<input type='text' name='username' id='userid' placeholder='Your ST_ID' >
<input type='password' name='password' required='required'>
</form>
 <input type='submit' name='resultbtn'  id='submit' value='Log In' >
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
$login = $_GET['login'];

setcookie("username","$username",time()+86400);

if($login=='yes') {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("users");
    $get = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM members_info WHERE username='$username' and password='$password' ");
    $result = mysql_result($get,0);

if($result !=1){
    echo "error with login";
}
else {
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

$sqll = "SELECT * FROM members_info WHERE username='$username' ";
$myqu = mysql_query($sqll,$con);
    include 'info.php';
  }
}
?>
```

**info.php**

```
...
<form method='post' action='mmbrs_inf.php'>
<input type='text' name='stname' placeholder='Your Name'>
<input type='text' name='stfname' placeholder='Father's Name'>
<input type='date' name='birthday'>
<input type='text' name='city'  placeholder='Your City'>
<select name='Select1'>
                <option>50</option>
                <option>60</option>
                <option>70</option>
                <option>80</option>
                <option>90</option>
                <option>100</option>
</select>

<input type='Reset' value='Reset' name='resetall'/>
    <input type='submit' value='Send'  name='submit'/>

</form>
...
```

and **mmbrs_inf.php**

```
$stname = $_POST['stname'];
$stfname = $_POST['stfname'];
$birthday = $_POST['birthday'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$english_dgree =$_POST['eng_dgree'];
//connect
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("users");


//check if submit is pressed 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //inserting
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members_info (student_name,student_father,birthdate,mycity,english) VALUES($stname,$stfname,$birthday,$city,$english_dgree) 
WHERE username='$_COOKIE[username]' ");
    echo"Your Informations Has Been Sent Successfully,....";        
}
else{
echo"An Error Has Accoure ";
}
```

It shows me the message "Your Informations Has Been Sent Successfully,...." but nothing is inserted in my database.

Comment: Firstly, forms don't have name attributes, elements do.

Comment: thanx @fred-ii ^_^ i always Press the "Vote Up" i was thing its the "Accepting Answer" my bad , thanks for help

Comment: @MrB: I recommend that you do not go live with this code, as it is extremely unsafe. You have SQL injection problems here, as well as unhashed passwords: two serious vulnerabilities. This code will allow an attacker to log in as anyone without knowing the password (a password of `' OR 1=1 --` will work for anyone - look at the resulting SQL to see why this is).

Comment: @halfer thanx bro iam not go live with this code , its just a small project to my teacher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT` statements do *not* have a `WHERE` clause. Either you are inserting a new row or updating one. You can't do both at the same time.

Also, you are missing quotes around your string values.

So do:

```
INSERT INTO members_info 
(student_name,student_father,birthdate,mycity,english_dgree) 
VALUES('$stname','$stfname','$birthday','$city','$english_dgree');
```

or:

```
 UPDATE members_info 
 SET student_name = '$stname', 
     student_father = '$stfname', 
     birthdate = '$birthday', 
     mycity = '$city', 
     english_dgree = '$english_dgree'
 WHERE username='$_COOKIE[username]';
```

Comment: Eek! Can we have a mention of the stonking great SQL injection vuln here?